# Java 8 - Map between class to one of its function

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have multiple types of objects, I'd like to generalise the 'id' of the objects in a way that will dynamically change what field is selected as the id.

Example

```
public class ObjectA{
  //Attribute name attA
  private String attA;
  .... More attributes
  public String getAttA(){
      return attA
  }

  .....More getters/setters
}
public class ObjectB{
  //Attribute named attB
  private String attB;
  .... More attributes
  public String getAttB(){
      return attB
  }

  .... More getters and setters
}
```

Id like to be able to run something like this:

```
Map<????, ????> customIdMap = new HashMap<>();
//We decide that ObjectA main attribute is AttA
customIdMap.add(ObjectA.class, ObjectA::getAttA);
//We decide that ObjectB main attribute is AttB
customIdMap.add(ObjectB.class, ObjectB::getAttB);
```

Then I'll be able to have a list of general objects and ill be able to retrieve their ids from the map if it is a known object with:

```
public String getCustomId(Object object){
   if(customIdMap.contains(object.getClass()){
      //Parameters are messed up, but this is the general idea of how 
      //i thought this would look
      return customIdMap.get(object.getClass()).apply(object);
   }
}
```

The code above does not run since getAttA is a call to a none static method in a static context so i assume this maybe should be wrapped in some kind of generic object.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4):

Preferably you change `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` to have a common interface. If that's not possible you can put them into a map like this:

```java
Map<Class<? extends Object>, Function<Object, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(ObjectA.class, a -> ((ObjectA) a).getAttA());
map.put(ObjectB.class, b -> ((ObjectB) b).getAttB());
```

EDIT:
Or if you would like to encapsulate it into a *typesafe heterogeneous container*:

```java
public static class ToIdMap {
    private final Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <X> void put(Class<X> clazz, Function<X, String> func) {
        map.put(clazz, (Function<Object, String>) func);
    }

    public String toIdString(Object o) {
        return map.get(o.getClass()).apply(o);
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Note that neither of these solutions work for subclasses, but it could be supported by traversing the class hierarchy in `toIdString`.

Comment: @Eugene actually I tried something a bit different. This version will pass compilation. Still doesn't look great in my opinion.

Comment: It's quick and dirty. You might want to look up "typesafe heterogeneous containers" (http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8), if this is _too_ quick and dirty.

Answer (score 2):

Your wording is a bit unclear, but I assume you want to get the ID of an object, even when they are different classes. This is the problem that `interface`s solve.

You can create an `interface`, with one method called `getId()`, which will return the id. Then, you can just call `getId()` on any type of object with an id.

For example:

```
public interface Identifiable {
    String getId();
}

public class ObjectA implements Identifiable {
    // same for ObjectB

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Then, in your code:

```
Identifiable i1 = new ObjectA();
Identifiable i2 = new ObjectB();

System.out.println(i1.getId());
System.out.println(i2.getId());
```

EDIT:

It still looks like an interface is the cleanest way of solving your problem. For completeness, the following will work:

```
Map<Class, Function<?, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(Object1.class, (Object1 o) -> o.getAttrA);  // repeat for ObjectB
```

It can then be called with:

```
if (obj instanceof Object1) return map.get(Object1.class).apply((ObjectA) obj);
```

Comment: This is not what i asked, please re read the question. I'll try to edit it to be more clearer

Comment: your question: "*Can it be done?*" - the answer "Yes, it can be done" [:-)  (defining a static method in each class ? or reflection?  or even using `java.lang.invoke`? - but the solution given here is probably easier (to understand and implement))

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this weird solution:

```
class  Mapping<T> {
        private Function<T, String> idFunc;

        public Mapping(Function<T, String> idFunc) {
            this.idFunc = idFunc;
        }

        public String apply(T obj) {
            return idFunc.apply(obj);
        }
    }

}

 private Map<Class, Mapping> mappings = new HashMap<>();
 mappings.put(ObjectA.class, new Mapping<>(ObjectA::getAttA);
 mappings.put(ObjectB.class, new Mapping<>(ObjectB::getAttB);

public String getObjectID(Object object){
      String id = null;
      if(mappings.containsKey(object.getClass())){
          id = mappings.get(object.getClass()).apply(object);
      }
      return id;
  }
```